# Royalslider width Issue

Tags: jquery, css, slider

I am trying to put Royalslider inside a div using .toggleSlide .[image]
But once i bring up the slide, the slides are only 100px wide. Here is a screenshot as you can see the red. I have it att 100% in the css aswell.

Here is my site: http://adl.clemenger.com.au/adamexperiment/Responsive%20Adam%20Web/home_11.html
Click on one of those Colorful boxes and jquery should pop up a div above it.

Any help? I tried disecting it with inspect element but it seems it could be a javascript issue perhaps, but im not enterierly sure. If you shrink the browser window then re-open it, it appears how it should be. Which is strange.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I saw in your source the following script

```
<!---Autoscroll--->
<script type="text/javascript">
var $root = $('html, body');
$('a').click(function() {
    $root.animate({
        scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined (repeated 5 times)
    }, 500);
    return false;
});
</script>
```

whenever I click on a link below the slider, it will trigger above handler, but `scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset()` is `undefined` so you can't retrieve the `top` property and that will rise error every time you click on the link, please re-check again that logic.